# positioning an image next to a menu bar with html/css

Tags: html, css

I am very new to html and css.  I am trying to build my first website.  I would like to have a picture on the same line as a nav bar, with the picture to the left.  I first tried using some prewritten code for a drop down nav bar, but I was unable to position an image to the left of it.  I tried some very basic code, but I still cannot figure our how to put a div (my image) next to a nav.  I don't quite know when to use `position`  and when to use `float`.  My goal is simple to start.  Get a div and nav to sit side-by side.  Here is the html I am using to test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Nav and div
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleside.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <img src="images/basil.jpg" alt="picture here" height="20%" width="20%">
</div>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Big Friendly Button</li>
        <li>TARDIS</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Can Anyone point me to a starting place for how to move these elements around?  Thank you!

Comment: What CSS is in your styleside.css file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common methods of forcing two block (commonly `div`) elements to sit beside each other.

### Floats

Floats are used to force elements to strictly align along the left or right of a page. However, they are also useful for placing two block elements beside one another:

```
div.image {
    float: left;
}
nav {
    float: left;
}
```

See this <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wCV2X/1/)</kbd>

One key advantage floating elements over inline blocks is that floating elements don't have a default margin to space text (see Inline blocks section).

You can also change the code under `nav` to `float: right;` which will separate the image and nav on separate sides of the screen.

### Inline blocks

Inline blocks are often used to display block elements inside a paragraph. But since two inline elements are placed beside each other given enough room, we can use these to position blocks horizontally:

```
div.image {
    display: inline-block;
}
nav {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And the <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrXsN/1/)</kbd>.

In the Fiddle I've colored the nav red to show the space in between the two elements. If you did the same for the floating elements, you'll see no space between the image and the nav. However, here there is a small margin caused by the default spacing given to `inline-block` elements - the browser wants to put space between an inline element and the surrounding text. To get rid of the space, you must add

```
body {
    font-size: 0;
}
nav {
    font-size: 12pt;
}
```

Why would you want no spacing? We often want widths described in percentages. However, if you were to keep the spacing while specifying percentages that add up to 100%, the second element would spill over onto the next line because we didn't take the extra spacing into account: see this <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrXsN/2/)</kbd>.

Comment: Thank You. The Fiddle was very helpful.  I am trying to use a much more complex drop down bar and it won't align the same.  But I have a much simpler problem:  When I add a simple paragraph like this [code] <p> this is a paragraph </p> [code] It gets all squished because my div and nav are moved with float.  Do I need to arrange paragraphs and tables with float as well?

Comment: You'll have to wrap the header and specify `overflow: hidden` to the wrapping block. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wCV2X/4/

Comment: Thanks!  the use of {code} <header> {/code} is very useful.  I am not sure if The floats can be applied to the tutorial I followed for a dropdown menu, but I will work at it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <sytle> // Put this in css
  .anynames{ // this css is for position an image to the left
   position:relative;
   float:left;
  }
 </sytle>

    <div id="anynames"> //<---- Id this use to indicate specific DIV
     <img src="images/basil.jpg" alt="picture here" height="20%" width="20%" />
        </div>
```

If this is correct Mark it if this is not We Finds ways :D

Answer (score 0):

Your two elements div and nav need to be formated in CSS. Like this:

```
<style>
.myDiv{
display:inline-block;
width:50%;
}
nav{
display:inline-block;
width:50%;
}
</style>
```

You must enter in a class for div to understand this code

```
<div class="myDiv">
```

The code inline-block will allow elements that are smaller then the remaining width of the page to be stacked beside it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it insures that the element is exactly half of the page width. So that there is space for the other element to sit beside it