# Dilema with heading, nav, and floating

Tags: html, css

I used another post ([positioning an image next to a menu bar with html/css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942646/positioning-an-image-next-to-a-menu-bar-with-html-css)), and it worked well, but now my heading is acting really weird!  If you look at the result of the example code in full screen, you'll see some of it is stuck next to my menu bar. May someone please help me?  I want my heading to be BELOW my menu bar.

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
h1 {
    font-family: comic sans ms;
    float: top;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 4px solid orange;
    border-radius: 500px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 16px;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    border-right: 2px solid orange;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}
nav ul li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: orange;
}
nav {
    display: inline;
}
div {
    float: left;
}
nav {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/example.css"/>
    <div>
        <img src="images/example.jpg">
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="example.html">Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="random.html">Random</a></li>
            <li><a href="blah-blah.html">Blah Blah</a></li>
            <li><a href="other.html">Other</a></li>
            <li><a href="something-else.html">Something Else</a></li>
            <li><a href="more.html">More</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Example Example Example Example Example Example Example</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html is invalid, you're not supposed to place those html tags inside the `<head>`. Anyway, I think your css is way too invasive, setting a `float` for every `div` on the page? Definitely too aggressive, I removed some of those unnecessary floats and set the nav to be `inline-block`

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
h1 {
    font-family: comic sans ms;
}
nav {
display: inline-block;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 4px solid orange;
    border-radius: 500px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 16px;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    border-right: 2px solid orange;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}
nav ul li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/example.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
        <img src="images/example.jpg">
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="example.html">Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="random.html">Random</a></li>
            <li><a href="blah-blah.html">Blah Blah</a></li>
            <li><a href="other.html">Other</a></li>
            <li><a href="something-else.html">Something Else</a></li>
            <li><a href="more.html">More</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1>Example Example Example Example Example Example Example</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!